# Controlling ellipsis style in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting, ellipsis

I implement Search in a web application that looks similar to the browser's "Find" feature. 
I want to highlight the searched strings on the page.  The search-string is often a substring of longer string that is shown with ellipsis.

I want to highlight the search-string wherever it appears, and if it is found in the part of text replaced by ellipsis, then I want to highlight the ellipsis itself.

How can I do that?

Comment: I suspect that what you're asking will be very tricky, if not impossible in pure CSS, because firstly, I'm not sure that you get much control over the styling of a CSS ellipsis, and secondly even if you can style it how you want, I don't think it gives you the ability to tell what parts of the text are visible. Also, what about edge cases, like if the search string is partially hidden, or if it appears more than once, and only one is hidden?

Comment: Can you show some code, tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I'd be happy with a JavaScript solution, if such exists.  Is there a way to know what part of the text is visible?  The edge cases are simple: if any part of the search-string is hidden then the ellipsis should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following components to implement it:

- An `overflow:hidden` container element
- An `overflow:auto` content element
- A `position:absolute` highlight element
- A class attribute to get/set the state

  Here are a few demos that comprise the aforementioned requirements:
- [Case Sensitive Search Bookmarklet](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2010/09/regular-expression-search-bookmarklet.html)
- [CSS Overflow Highlight](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/text-overflow.html)